# External php script to insert products into magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am switching an old php website to a magento website. I have over 10,000 products which I would want to import into magento. The new magento website already has the needed categories and a few products. I am planning to write a php script to import those products right away from the old database into magento database.

Is this a feasible idea? Any issues I should be warned of?

If all good, is there anyway to get database tables mapping to create a product in a right category in magento? i.e. product id, name, images and description inserted right away into magento database and picked up/displayed as normal. Appreciate help.

Comment: why don't you try https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Comment: @JayGhosh, thanks, will give it a try and be back. leme know if you know of any better way.

Comment: Any idea if magmi would help me easily import images too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The easier and faster way is that you can use MAGMI (https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/). 
   This is a great tool for importing products in Magento. But you need to learn first how to use it.

OR You can use Magento default import/export feature to do same. Please check given below URLs how to default feature.

a: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/import-products.htm

b: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-exportimport-data-in-csv-files.html#gref

Comment: Thanks Abhinav, will try the links and be back. Any idea if magmi would help me easily import images too?

Answer (score 0):

The easier and faster way would be to use MAGMI (https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/). We always using this great tool for the product importers.

Comment: Any idea if magmi would help me easily import images too? Any limit of products/time?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, make one csv file which contains all details of products to be added along with category details.

Include this csv file in php script. Run that php file at url.

This is my rough suggestion. If you can make most out of it.

Comment: what do you mean by 'run that php file at url'? can you please explain?

Comment: will appreciate if this is a way to right away run a php scripts that inserts from csv to database. but again, i have seen people warning about magento db structure and indexing getting messed up.

Comment: I mean if you have made that php script as sample.php and it is at root directory like magento_project/sample.php . Then enter this same address at addressbar in browser. Hope I'm clear!

Comment: cool. thats what i am trying to achieve in fact. but my problem, the script would insert right away from csv to magento db? if yes, any easy way to know which tables and relationships?